# Let $\rho$ f.d. rep of a nilpotent Lie algebra such that $\rm{det} \rho(X) = 0$, $\forall X$. Then $\exists v \neq 0$: $\rho(X)v = 0, \forall X$.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Could you help me with this question?

Let $\mathcal{g}$ be a nilpotent Lie algebra over $k$ and $\rho$ a representation of $\mathcal{g}$ in a finite-dimensional nonzero vector space $V$ over $k$. Suppose that det $\rho (X) = 0$ for all $X \in \mathcal{g}$. Show that there is a nonzero vector $v \in V$ such that $\rho(X)v = 0$ for all $X \in \mathcal{g}$.

Comment: Do you really mean that $\det \rho(X)=0$ for all $X$, or rather that all $\rho(X)$ are nilpotent ? I think you need nilpotent.

Comment: Yes, I mean $\det \rho(X) = 0$ for all $X$ in the nilpotent Lie algebra $\mathcal{g}$. I found this problem in the book of Lie Groups and Lie Algebras by Varadarajan.

Comment: Yes, it is question $21$ in chapter $3$. It follows from Lie's theorem, a weight space decomposition, and Theorem $3.5.2$.

Answer (score 2):

Typically Engel's theorem on nilpotent Lie algebras is proved with the following Theorem:

*Theorem*: If $ρ \colon \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V )$ is a representation on a (non-zero) vector space $V$ such that $\rho(a)$ is a *nilpotent* linear transformation for any $a ∈ \mathfrak{g}$, then $V$ has a non-zero vector $v$ such that $\rho(\mathfrak{g})v = 0$.

For a proof, see for example Proposition $2.3$ [here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~anskor/LIE.PDF). This theorem is usually proved in a book on Lie algebras.

Edit: The question is exactly question $21$ in chapter $3$ of Varadarajan's book.
The way I would prove it is by using the weight space decomposition for representations of nilpotent Lie algebras, i.e., Theorem $9.1$ [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=l8nJCNiIQAAC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=weight+space+decomposition+for+representations+of+nilpotent+Lie+algebras+vinberg&source=bl&ots=pI8S_ogVaA&sig=Nil02IfNMnU5mkTqLGYU-lIvO3Q&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDsK3hierJAhVF0xoKHbBtBDsQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=weight%20space%20decomposition%20for%20representations%20of%20nilpotent%20Lie%20algebras%20vinberg&f=false). Then the assumption $\det \rho(X)=0$ for all $X$ implies that  $\lambda_i(x)=0$ in the theorem, so that all operators $\rho(X)$ are nilpotent. This follows first over the complex numbers, but of course then also holds over the real numbers. Now the claim concerning the common eigenvector follows by the above result. Note that the proof of Theorem $9.1$ uses Lie's theorem.

Comment: The Lie algebra in question is assumed to be nilpotent.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, that is true. But is the assumption enough in general ?

Comment: I actually have no idea, but my guess would be that it is not.

Comment: I have seen the proof of Engel's theorem using the theorem above, whose proof I also reviewed. However I haven't been able to modify any of these proofs to answer the main (initial) question of this post. Please, if you came up with some idea, let me know